# How can 3rd party app read files under /system/?

Tags: android, permissions

Now i have a requirement to read files under /system/.
As far as i know, only system app have access to these files, how can a 3rd party app read these files?

Answer (score 0):

That may have something to do with the app's permission. One app that i knew that can access system files would be ES File Explorer. I think you will be able to do this with a READ and WRITE to storage permissions. Read more about permissions [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html).

Comment: ES File explore can read system file without Root permission?

Comment: ESfe has a feature that will enable disable root access. According to https://seo-michael.co.uk/enable-root-browsing-on-es-file-explorer/